# How to set charset to UTF8 in pdo oracle(oci)

Tags: php, oracle, pdo, utf-8

Here is my php codes

```
$tns = "
 (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS_LIST =
        (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
      )
        (CONNECT_DATA =
          (SERVICE_NAME = myservice)
      )
 )";
$conn = new PDO("oci:dbname=" . $tns, 'user', 'pass');
```

When I try to set the charset to UTF8 like this:

```
$conn = new PDO("oci:dbname=" . $tns . ";charset=UTF8", 'user', 'pass');
```

will get:
`ERROR: SQLSTATE[HY000]: OCINlsCharSetNameToId: unknown character set name  (/app/software/php-5.6.30/ext/pdo_oci/oci_driver.c:610)pdo is NULL`

I have already set the NLS_LANG to `AMERICAN_AMERICA.UTF8`, but looks like my host machine need to restart, I can NOT do it now.

So, what should I do can change the charset to utf8 with pdo/oci connected to oracle database??

And I want:

1. **NOT** modify the charset in oracle databse
2. **ONLY** use pdo, not oci_connect
3. **NOT** restart my host machine

Comment: What version is your Oracle DB? You may need to use `AL32UTF8` instead

Comment: Oracle version is 11g.  `$conn = new PDO("oci:dbname=" . $tns . ";charset=AL32UTF8", 'user', 'pass');` get the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Takes me 4 hours to solve this:

1. Modify the `/etc/sysconfig/httpd` file by command `vim /etc/sysconfig/httpd`
2. Add the codes below at the end of this file

   ```
   export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/app/oracle/orahome/lib
   export ORACLE_HOME=/app/oracle/orahome
   export NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.UTF8
   ```
3. restart apache by command `service httpd restart`

You have to do **NOTHING** about your `pdo` or `oracle` or `host machine`.
If you don't know the variable's value, just `echo $ORACLE_HOME` in command line.

BTW,

All these three variables should be set in `/ect/profile`, and you'd better make them same in these two files.

Comment: Note, "UTF8" character set is a misnomer for UCSE-8 encoding. Real UTF-8 is character set "AL32UTF8" However as long you stay in unicode BMP they are identical.

Comment: There is a section in http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/php/underground-php-oracle-manual-098250.html on how to set environment variables for PHP OCI8.  It will apply to PDO_OCI as well.  If you use php-fpm, note that PDO_OCI is affected by the php-fpm 'buglet' which prevents PHP from reading php-fpm configuration file until after PDO_OCI is initialized, see https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=74631

Comment: I'm not using `php-fpm`, thanks anyway~  @ChristopherJones

Comment: Same problem when running from crontab: in my case the solution was to set the environment variable **ORACLE_HOME** inside crontab or before the task directive as export. Thanks!